# Returning multiple values in a python function

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, return

Is there an easy way to have a function return multiple variables that can be easily accessed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to do this is a tuple, which can just be used with `return`:

```
>>> def multi_return():
        return 1, 2, 3

>>> multi_return()
(1, 2, 3)
```

You can use tuple unpacking to bind the return values to separate names:

```
>>> a, b, c = multi_return()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Alternatively, you can `return` a single list, which will be treated much the same way:

```
>>> def list_return():
        return [1, 2, 3]

>>> list_return()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a, b, c = list_return()
>>> b
2
```